# Zero padding the employee no. field in Talend Job

Tags: talend, tmap

While developing Talend job using tMap,
I am in need of executing zero padding of a field that contains numbers (example: 1542) and is of 20 characters length.

1. Will my proposed formula

`StringHandling.STR('0',20-(StringHandling.LEN(row1.eno)))+row1.eno`

```
work?
```

2. If not, what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: Please specify and format your question & code according to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use StringHandling.LPAD(row1.eno, 20, '0') or something of a kind?
Left zero padding is what you require, if I understood you correctly...

R

Answer (score 0):

A simple `String.format()` can do that :

```
String.format("%020d",row1.eno)
```